# Algebra of the Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I'm reading an economics paper on labour market search which uses the binomial distribution in one of its arguments but with a simplification that I cant quite derive.

The idea is this. Suppose that there are $n$ workers and $m$ firms. Each worker applies to a firm with probability $\frac{1}{m}$. Each firm has only one job available, if more than one worker applies to the firm the job is allocated randomly.

The probability that a worker gets the job at the firm he/she applies to is given by:

\begin{equation} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}\bigg(\frac{1}{m}\bigg)^j\bigg(1-\frac{1}{m}\bigg)^{n-1-j} \frac{1}{j+1} = \frac{1-\big(1-\frac{1}{m}\big)^n}{n/m} \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{j+1}: \text{probability of our worker being selected if $j$ other workers apply} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\bigg(\frac{1}{m}\bigg)^j\bigg(1-\frac{1}{m}\bigg)^{n-1-j}: \text{probability of exactly $j$ of the other workers apply when there are $m$ firms} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}: \text{ways of choosing a group of $j$ from $n$} 
\end{equation}

We sum this product to obtain our total probability.

So I think I understand how the left hand side works but I can't derive the simple expression on the right hand side. I imagine the proof is similar to proving that the mean of the binomial distribution is $E(X)=np$.

If someone could give me a nudge in the correct direction I would really appreciate it. I would like to be able to do this myself but i cant see how to tackle the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left hand side can be simplified to
\begin{equation} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^j\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n-1-j}\frac{1}{j+1} \\= \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{(j+1)!(n-1-j)!}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^j\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n-1-j}  \end{equation}
Define index  $k=j+1$, so that the summation can be expressed as
\begin{equation} \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n-k}  \end{equation}
The summation is very close to a binomial expansion, just one index off. Can you proceed further?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I can take it from there. Very helpful solution.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You use that 
$$
\binom{n-1}{j}·\frac1{j+1}=\frac1n·\binom{n}{j+1}
$$
and complete the expression to contain the full form from the binomial theorem for
$$
1=\left(\left(1-\frac1m\right)+\frac1m\right)^n
$$